# Application of settings.gradle to Gradle build with non-standard build name

Tags: build, gradle, settings

I have an application that is built with a build script named linuxApp.gradle. We have specified in settings.gradle

`rootProject.name = "JobThreader"`

As long as the root project folder is also named "JobThreader", when we execute the installApp task from the application plugin, the application is built to

`JobThreader/build/install/JobThreader`

However, if the root project folder is any other name, like "workspace" in the case of Jenkins, then the application is built to

`workspace/build/install/workspace`

We have verified this behavior both on our Linux Jenkins server and our local Windows machine.

We have attempted the following commands with identical results

`gradlew clean installApp -b linuxApp.gradle`

gradlew clean installApp -b linuxApp.gradle -c settings.gradle

How can we get the application to install to workspace/build/install/JobThreader in our Jenkins example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `-b` is used, any settings script will be ignored. (`-b` can be useful for experimentation, but isn't typically used for real builds.) When `-b` is not used and a settings script is found or passed explicitly via `-c`, it's up to that settings script to configure the names of build scripts. For example:

```
rootProject.buildFileName = "linuxApp.gradle"
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! We're using a non-standard build name because of inter-team politics and your solution works wonderfully.